# Send a card to microsoft Teams with data from external database

Tags: c#, database, bots, webhooks, microsoft-teams

How can I best send message from my c # code to A teams channel, In my code I retrieve data from an external database And want to show this data using a card in my teams "team"... Does it work to use an incoming webhook or do i need to build a bot?

Comment: You can create a  Incoming webhook and call it using HTTPClient from your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  Incoming webhook and call it using HTTP Client from your C# code.

Bot is not required to only send the data to Teams channel.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming

Comment: Okay thanks think this is what I'm looking for ..
Since I am very new to c #, there are some things I wonder ...
Am I supposed to make HTTP Client calls at the URL I get when I register my "Conector -Incoming Webhook" on teams or should it come from somwhere else?

Comment: at a time of registration of Connector -Incoming Webhook you get the URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#create-an-incoming-webhook-1